# How to unregister a drone from an Onboard SDK application

Tags: dji-sdk

We are developing an Onboard SDK application on our payload. To use this payload on a new drone, the drone needs to register the application using DJI Assistent 2 running on a laptop with internet connection.

To make the experience more pleasant for our customers, I would like to automate this a bit further. To test this on our development drone, I would need to unregister our Onboard SDK application on the drone.

Is this possible, and how can I do that, if so?

Best regards,

Bart

Comment: refresh the drone firmware will auto-erase the osdk linked account info. Thats why ever time when you flash new firmware you have this NEW_DEVICE_ERROR. so this should solve your question

Comment: Ok, thanks @DrYuanShenghai! I will give that a try.